# Docker - correct approach for cms development

Tags: docker, content-management-system, omeka

I am currently setting up docker for development purpose.

The goal would be to easily setup mysql, apache, php, and the cms (Omeka).

I managed to rewrite a dockerfile and dockercompose that automatically setup the cms for a normal user, but i need to be able to access the CMS source code i wget'd during build.

From my understanding, volumes/binds aren't the solution because they only access files added *after* build (i tried anyway and couldn't access the files).

Should i write a script the run the compose routine, and *then* download the files and do the things necessary for installing the cms, or is there a more docker approach to this ?

Here is my docker-compose :

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      //some vars. irrelevant
  
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    depends_on: 
      - db
    ports: 
      - 8081:80

  omeka:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      //some vars. Irrelevant
    volumes: 
      - type: bind
        source: ./www/
        target: /var/www/

volumes: 
  www:
```

And my Dockerfile :

```
FROM php:8.0.3-apache
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      [some packages]
RUN docker-php-ext-install exif mysqli

# Install omeka
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN git clone --recursive https://github.com/omeka/Omeka.git
RUN chown -R root.www-data Omeka && chmod 775 Omeka
WORKDIR /var/www/Omeka
[....]
# Copy some files, run some commands, set some rights

# Configure apache
COPY omeka.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/omeka.conf
[....]

# Configure php
[...]

# Add init script
COPY run.sh /run.sh
RUN dos2unix "/run.sh"
RUN chmod 755 /*.sh

EXPOSE 443

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

Running this (i removed some vars, and of course config files are lacking for clarity purposes) gives me a www folder that stays empty.

I don't quite understand how i could do this, as i don't exactly know how the files are persistent or not when re-running `docker-compose p -d`

This is my first docker file as well.

Thank you

Comment: I believe you can edit your files in mounted directory so that you see the changes live. Did you try that in `./www/`?

Comment: Well, when i run the container, the www folder is created, some files i copy there after are copied, but not the ones i wget'd during build. Should i move the installation of the to cms to the run.sh file ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your `run.sh` is doing, but you can I think you can move wgeted files to mounted directory and then build, or you can add `wget` command to your `run.sh` file and build it again